# True or False: There is a $6\times 6$ matrix $A$ with $\text{Rank}(A)=4$ and $A^3 =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

I understand how to do it if the question changed $A^3$ to $A^2$, because then you can just use the rank–nullity theorem. $\text{Rank}+\text{Nullity}=6$, $\text{Rank}=4$ so $\text{Nullity}=2$ so of the $6$ column vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_6,$ only two of them satisfy $Av_i=0$. I don't know what to do with $A^3$ however because I'm not sure what nullity says about $A^2v_i$.

Comment: Let $e_1,e_2,\dots$ be the standard basis.  Let $A$ map $e_i\mapsto e_{i+2}$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ and $e_5\mapsto 0$ and $e_6\mapsto 0$.  What is the rank of $A$?  What is $A^3$?

Comment: More generally, when doing questions like this, think about using Jordan Normal Forms. Usually, there will be JNF example if there's an example at all (and provably so, in this case, but I digress). You can multiple Jordan blocks, with a total size of $6$ (e.g. $3$ and a $3$? Or $2$ and $4$? Maybe, $1$, $1$, $1$, and $3$?). The condition $A^3 = 0$ means (among other things) that the matrix is nilpotent, and hence the only eigenvalue possible is $0$. This reduces the JNF possibilities down to a finite list!

Comment: @JMoravitz wow...but how'd you come up with that?

Comment: @Sachin A way to think about it is (1) send a 2 dimensional subspace to $0$ to get rank $4$, say $y,z$ axes. (2) You want more things to go to $0$ in higher powers, so  send another 2 dimensional subspace $A$ to the $y,z$ axes. (3) Send another such subspace $B$ to $A$ and make sure that $A$, $B$ and the $y,z$ axes generate the whole $6$ dimensional domain.

Answer (score 3):

If $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Then

$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0  \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0  \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix}$

And

$A^3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $